# Scrape/Download mp3 files off website using shell command

Tags: bash, shell

First off, this is not for an assignment, this is a side tangent project to help with my shell knowledge. I am trying to make a simple shell script that, when given a text file of commands, runs each one in order until the one before it is done.

So far I have come up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/gome/Downloads/darknetdiaries.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  $line
done < "$input"
```

and in the separate text file I have:

```
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep10-wiretap-mishap.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep11-buyout.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep12-cryptowars.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep13-carna.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep14-opjustina2.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep15-illtill.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep16-eijah.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep17-finn.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep18-jackpot.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep19-aurora.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep1-pbx-hacking.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep20-mobman.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep21-black-duck-eggs.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep22-ministories1.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep23-levin.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep24-bayonet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep25-alberto.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep26-irs.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep27-chartbreakers.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep28-unit8200.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep29-stuxnet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep2-vtech.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep30-shamoon.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep31-hackergiraffe.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep32-thecarder.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep33-rockyou.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep34-foryoureyesonly.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep35-carbanak.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep36-jeremyfrommarketing.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep37-lvs.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep38-dark-caracal.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep39-3alarmlampscooter.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep3-diginotar.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep40-no-parking.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep41-just-visiting.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep42-ministories-vol2.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep43-ppp.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep44-zain.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep45-xbox1.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep46-xbox2.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep47-projectraven.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep48-opsocialist.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep49-elliot.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep4-talktalk.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep50-glowing-symphony.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep51-indopak-conflict.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep52-magecart.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep53-shadowbrokers.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep54-notpetya.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep55-noirnet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep56-jordan.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep57-ms08067.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep58-oxymonster.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep59-courthouse.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep5-asus.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep60-dawgyg.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep61-samy.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep62-cam.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep63-w0rmer.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep64-shadowphones.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep65-psyop.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep66-freakyclown.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep67-the-big-house.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep68-triton.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep69-humanhacker.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep6-jaysonstreet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep70-ghostexodus.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep71-fdff.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep72-bangladeshbank.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep73-wannacry.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep74-mikko.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep75-compromised-comms.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep76-knavesout.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep77-olympicdestroyer.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep7-manfred-part1.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep8-manfred-part2.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep9-mtgox.mp3
```

Currently getting no errors but it seems like it is just printing out all the lines and not *doing* anything. Here is a picture: [image]

**I really appreciate the help!**

**EDIT:**

The scripts above work how they should. One file is a text file of all the commands you would like to run and the other file is the shell script.

In the text doc, I filled it with links to all current episodes of Dark Net Diaries podcast: In order to get all the links, I first had to scan the web site using Owasp Zap and sort out the url's. After that, just pop it into a text file and add wget in front.

Comment: Use `source` command instead

Comment: Where? Instead of COMMAND_on?

Comment: Instead of the loops:  https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/source.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the command after the `echo "$line"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="PATH_TO_TEXT_FILE"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  $line
done < "$input"
```

Or remove `COMMAND_on` from the second while loop.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and after adding the correct path and I got the error: "command not found" in the command line after running my .sh file...

Comment: In that case `wget` is not in your path.

Comment: I am able to take one line out of the text file and pop it into the terminal in any location and it works fine... It downloads the mp3 file. I know I have wget downloaded correctly

Comment: What is the output of `which wget` ?

Comment: The path is: /usr/bin/wget

Comment: Should I just add this onto every line in my text file?

Comment: add `which wget` inside your script, before the `while` loop; does it still report `/usr/bin/wget` or does it report it cannot find `wget`?

Comment: That is one option, but `/usr/bin/` ought to be in your PATH already. Did you put any quotes around `$line` or in the input file?

Comment: Do you want me to post both of my files? It might be easier that way.

Comment: yes, it would help if you updated your question to include the latest version of your script so we know what we're dealing with; also include the complete error message(s) you are now receiving

Comment: Updated the question with the files.

Comment: I don't understand why it wont let me run the script with out using sudo... Although, it should still work. Tried running wget with sudo on one line and it worked.

Comment: You have to make the script executable: `chmod 755 DarkNetDownload.sh`. No need for `sudo`.

Comment: It works now! Thank you! I don't know what I did. Didn't touch permissions.

Comment: This will now download all the episodes of an awesome podcast.

Comment: Then it could be that the directory you are saving to is not writable by you (anymore).

Comment: Not sure. I was running the code in my downloads dir. Don't know why it wouldn't be writable...